Flask server function not yielding
I have a Flask app that has RAG pipeline in the background, we get responses from LLM in stream.
I have prints for debugging and its working fine.
parse_json_stream function prints but not yields.
def parse_json_stream(line):
    decoded_line = line.decode('utf-8')
    decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
    pos = 0
    while pos < len(decoded_line):
        try:
            result, json_end = decoder.raw_decode(decoded_line[pos:])
            if "text" in result:
                print(result["text"]) # works
                yield result["text"] # not works
            pos += json_end
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            pos += 1

And this is a part of my Flask app where I handle file uploads and response generation:
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
    def upload_file():
        # if file not provided
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return jsonify({'error': 'No file part'}), 400

        file = request.files['file']

        if file.filename == '':
            return jsonify({'error': 'No selected file'}), 400

        # if file provided
        if file:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
            file.save(file_path)
            print(f"file saved {file_path}")
            question = request.form.get('question', '')
            
        def generate():
            try:
                # we can use prompt_len to slice down the text, not using rn
                prompt_len, response = process_and_respond(file_path, question)
                print("********* Generate Funct **********")
                for line in response.iter_lines():
                    if line:
                        parsed_text = parse_json_stream(line)
                        # returns None if we reach the end of the stream
                        if parsed_text: # handle 'None' case
                            for text in parsed_text:
                                yield text
            finally:
                print(f"Deleting File {file_path}")
                os.remove(file_path)

        return Response(stream_with_context(generate()), content_type='text/plain')
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)

I send a post request and get that text intead of actual LLM response:
import requests

url = "http://ec2-11-11-1-1.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/"

files = {
    'file': ('file.pdf', open('file.pdf', 'rb'))
}
data = {
    'prompt': 'what is this file about?',
    'stream': 'True', 
    'min_tokens': 256,
    'max_tokens': 1024
}

response = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data, stream=True)
if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response)
# output
# <Response [200]>


When yielding from parse_json_stream generation, the result object named parsed_text in the statement parsed_text = parse_json_stream(line) is a generator object. You must iterate over the generator object to consume its values.

@OluwafemiSule thanks for your help. I updated the code and it’s working, but it currently yields the previously generated text along with an additional word or token. I want to modify it so that it only yields the most recently generated word rather than the entire previous answer. How can I achieve this?
